# Read&parse text file line by line in VBA - code keeps reading in everything all at once

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to read a text file of numbers into excel VBA and the code keeps reading everything in all at once, not line by line.
With this code, a regular test file (test.txt) reads line by line whereas the file I want (TJS-3_43874_Generated_TLE.txt) does not. I can cut the individual lines of TJS-3_43874_Generated_TLE.txt into a clean text file, line by line, and it will read properly but I have a large list of files and this isn't a great use of time. Is there a hidden character or something I'm missing?

I am hoping someone can shed light on what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

This is the format of basically every code I have read:

```
Sub testread()

Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, posLat As Integer, posLong As Integer

myFile = "C:\Users\TJS-3_43874_Generated_TLE.txt"
'myFile = "C:\Users\test.txt"

Open myFile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, textline
    text = text & textline
Loop
Close #1

End Sub
```

test.txt

```
Some information here..

latitude: 72n31
longitude: 15w27

Some information here..
```

TJS-3_43874_Generated_TLE.txt

```
1 43874U 18110A   20124.62500000  .00000092  00000-0  34605-0 0 00001
2 43874 000.0554 290.8570 0002993 254.0264 075.0858 01.00270444005065
```

Comment: also of note: The TJS-3_43874_Generated_TLE.txt can be read in by matlab and python's line-by-line readers just fine.

Answer (score 1):

`Line Input #` looks for either a Chr(13) character or a Chr(13)Chr(10) sequence to identify where one line stops and the next line starts. Some operating systems or programs generate files which only use Chr(10) to separate each line and `Line Input #` will read the contents of those files into one long line.

To check if this is the case for your file, try:

```
Line Input #1, textline

If InStr(textline, Chr$(10)) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Line contains embedded Chr(10) characters"
End If
```

Assuming that there are indeed embedded Chr(10) characters, then we can split `textline` into an array to recover the individual lines:

```
Dim sLines() As String
Dim vLine As Variant

sLines = Split(textline, Chr$(10))
For Each vLine In sLines
    MsgBox vLine
Next vLine
```

Note that `vLine` had to be a Variant to be used in the `For Each...Next` loop. Replace the `MsgBox vLine` part with whatever processing you need to perform on each line

Answer (score 0):

When reading a text file in VBA, the newlines are stripped on each line. When saving the line, append `vbCrLf`.

Try this code:

```
Sub testread()

    Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, posLat As Integer, posLong As Integer
    
    myFile = "C:\Users\TJS-3_43874_Generated_TLE.txt"
    'myFile = "C:\Users\test.txt"
    
    Open myFile For Input As #1
    
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        Debug.Print textline
        
        text = text & textline & vbCrLf
    Loop
    Debug.Print text
    Close #1

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there anything that can be done if the original 'newline character' doesn't seem to be read in from the original text file? Ex if I wanted to enclose each line in quotation marks before saving it to the "text" string? If it reads both lines in as one line, I don't see a way to tell where the first line ends. Thanks!